# Constraint problems with scrollable Stack View

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, constraints, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview

I'm developing a little app and I want to implement a view in the keyboard extension as the following image shows:

[image: What I want]

Now my app looks like this:

[image: What I have]

I want to implement top and bottom button constraints but I'm having problems because it creates a vertical scroll despite incrementing the height of the space above the keyboard because the buttons also increment their height:

[image: What I have tried]

My actual code is:

```
class CatboardBanner: ExtraView {

    var scrollView = UIScrollView()
    var stack = UIStackView()
    let button = UIButton()
    let button2 = UIButton()
    let button3 = UIButton()
    let button4 = UIButton()
    let button5 = UIButton()

    required init(globalColors: GlobalColors.Type?, darkMode: Bool, solidColorMode: Bool) {
        super.init(globalColors: globalColors, darkMode: darkMode, solidColorMode: solidColorMode)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.01)
        self.addSubview(scrollView)
        self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.scrollView.addSubview(self.stack)
        self.stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.stack.axis = .horizontal
        self.stack.spacing = 10

        button.setTitle("btn 1", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.roundedCorners(rounding: 5)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        button2.setTitle("btn 2", for: .normal)
        button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        button2.roundedCorners(rounding: 5)
        button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        button3.setTitle("btn 3", for: .normal)
        button3.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        button3.roundedCorners(rounding: 5)
        button3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        button4.setTitle("btn 4", for: .normal)
        button4.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        button4.roundedCorners(rounding: 5)
        button4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        button5.setTitle("btn 5", for: .normal)
        button5.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        button4.roundedCorners(rounding: 5)
        button5.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.stack.addArrangedSubview(button)
        self.stack.addArrangedSubview(button2)
        self.stack.addArrangedSubview(button3)
        self.stack.addArrangedSubview(button4)
        self.stack.addArrangedSubview(button5)
        self.updateAppearance()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func setNeedsLayout() {
        super.setNeedsLayout()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        self.scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true;
        self.scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true;
        self.scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true;
        self.scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true;

        self.stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        self.stack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.stack, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30)
        let widthConstraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button2, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        let heightConstraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button2, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30)
        let widthConstraint3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button3, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        let heightConstraint3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button3, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30)
        let widthConstraint4 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button4, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        let heightConstraint4 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button4, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30)
        let widthConstraint5 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button5, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        let heightConstraint5 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button5, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leadingConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint, widthConstraint2, heightConstraint2, widthConstraint3, heightConstraint3, widthConstraint4, heightConstraint4, widthConstraint5, heightConstraint5])
    }

    @objc func respondToSwitch() {
    }

    func updateAppearance() {
    }
}
```

ExtraView is the view in the keyboard extension where I'm working and its height is 50.

What I have tried in the 3rd image is to change the topAnchor constraint of the scrollView to 8 but unfortunatelly it didn't work out.

I hope you can help me with this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes! But i don't have problems with that issue. I'm interested in solving the constraints problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: “ExtraView is the view in the keyboard extension where I'm working and its height is 50.” And you have pinned the stack view height to the extra view, so its height is 50 too.

Comment: That was it! Now it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! If the problem was trivially solved, perhaps it would be advisable to delete the question.

Comment: Okay! I'm a little rookie so I don't know how this platform works. Could you help me out with this question too? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997286/unexpected-error-on-adding-a-button-action-in-the-keyboard-extension)